Collect phone and email with stripe PaymentElement using google pay
Is it possible to get user email and phone number from gpay when using stripe PaymentElement control? (https://docs.stripe.com/payments/payment-element)
I see that with the ExpressCheckoutElement, it is possible to specify emailRequired and phoneNumberRequired options (https://docs.stripe.com/elements/express-checkout-element/accept-a-payment#handle-click-event). I also see those options in the old PaymentRequestButtonElement with paymentRequest (https://docs.stripe.com/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button?client=react#mount-element)
Is there a way to achieve the same with PaymentElement? Right now the only contact info displayed for me in gpay window is user name. Thank you in advance.

At the moment, Stripe doesn't allow configuring this inside PaymentElement. You likely should report this as a feature request to their support team.
In the meantime, Stripe often recommends having both PaymentElement and ExpressCheckoutElement together on your page so that might solve the issue until they add a feature on PaymentElement.

I see, thank you. One more question if I may: if I go with ExpressCheckoutElement approach, how do I access the email and phone number - on the backend using payment intent, or is it possible to get it on the frontend somehow?

In the confirm callback you get the details in result when it's called. So if you log it you can see billingDetails with email and phone
